# Google Places Autocomplete not appearing

Tags: javascript, ember.js, google-places-api

Component

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.TextField.extend({
type: 'text',

didInsertElement: function() {
  this.$().addClass("form-control");
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),{types:['geocode']} //trying without jQuery, but still.
  );
}});
```

Template

```
{{gp-textfield id="autocomplete"}}
```

which renders to

```
<input id="autocomplete" type="text" class="ember-view ember-text-field form-control" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="off">
```

but still, i get:

```
InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

EDIT: Ember 2.6

cleaned up the code a bit, with no avail

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  this.$().addClass("form-control");
  var element = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element);
}
```

Comment: Not the solution to your problem, but you can use the the class properties ["classNames"](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_classNames) for specifying class names for a component. It will concat them to the class Names of the parent class as well, and any classes specified in the template by the `class` attribute.

Comment: Also it could be related to the issue, but instead of overriding didInsertElement, i'd recommend defining a new method but define it like `Ember.on('didElementInsert', <your function>)`, it'll still run on insert but without overriding the didInsertElement method in parent classes, alternatively you can call this._super(arguments) at the start of the function, but I feel the former is tidier.

Comment: More info on overriding [`didInsertElement`](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_integrating-with-third-party-libraries-with-code-didinsertelement-code), more on [`Ember.on`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Function.html#method_on)

Comment: As for your actual question, consider using [`this.get('element')`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_element) to get the dom element of the component instead of the global id (in the event you want to use more than one typeahead), that and [going by the example in the google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete#try-it-yourself) for this, i think you need to bind the typeahead to a map amoung other things (although maybe you're doing that else where in the code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the Network tab in chrome.

Apparently my API key was not authorized to use this feature and i had to enable it.